# Thread design and design and calling a function in one thread from another in C++ Win32

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Say you have two threads in Win32.  Let's say the main UI thread launches a worker thread A. Let's say when Thread A was created a pointer back to a class in the main thread was sent to thread A.  At some point during it's processing, Thread A calls a function in the main thread via the pointer.  Thread A and the main thread will never contend for the same data and never call the same function at the same time.

Is this bad practice?

And if it is then what would be the correct design for this functionality.  Thread A needs access to the function in the main thread say to access data kept in the main thread.  It's expected though that Thread A will never call the function in the main thread when the main thread is accessing the data.  Thus there would be no contention over the data.  However, the main thread may start up again while thread a is still calling into the function in the main thread.

Does this matter or is it generally OK to call functions in other threads so long as there is no data contention and the functions being called into are reentrant?

Comment: If the worker thread calls a function, it doesn't matter where that function was defined, it will always be called in the context of the worker thread. You can't "call" functions in other threads.

Comment: Joachim, Thanks for the info.  What do you mean by "can't call function in other threads".  Are you saying it's bad practice to?  If so then what is the correct design to call functions in threads in Win32 -- using messages in an invisible window thread (which takes longer than a direct call)?

Comment: I really mean that *all* functions called from e.g. "thread A" will be in the context of "thread A". To have a function being called in another threads context, you have to use [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing), and let the other thread do the actual function call.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is 100% correct, (J - you should post it as an answer).  You cannot call another thread, only signal it.  Function call/return works in exactly the same way in any thread - the main thread created by the process loader and any other threads that you process may create.  The only function calls that can change thread context are those system calls, ('interupts'), that can change the set of running threads, eg. Sleep(), SetEvent, ReleaseSemaphore.

Comment: @brimaa "Thread A calls a function in the main thread..." No, functions do not belong to a thread. They execute in any thread that calls them.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.  In Win32, if messaging is the only (or best) way to call functions on threads then you might expect there to be more support for thread only message pumps in Win32.  There is not much for threads without windows and instead you have to use a fake invisible window to get one.  It's not clear in the MSFT documentation if just calling GetMessage and DispatchMessage gets you a message pump in a worker thread or whether you need a handle to an (invisible) window attached to that thread.

Comment: Calling GetMessage/PeekMessage will get you a Windows message queue. I've seen it in the docs somewhere, and done it often.  You don't have to create a window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads are global in a process, shared between all threads. There's no such thing as "a function in the main thread".

What matters is how the data is shared. A function consists of two things: the code itself, and the data that it operates on.

The code is, as a general rule, static. This is why it is fine for code to be freely shared between threads. There is never any contention on it.

It's a different story for the data though. You need to be sure that there is no incorrect contention on any data shared between multiple threads. So long as you are content that this is so, then it is fine to call the same function from multiple threads.

Comment: +1 and one potential gotcha - it may not be obvious to everyone that a `static` function variable would be shared between threads. That's why functions like `strtok` use thread-local static variables instead.